# Jmeter: Unable to connect via SAML protocol

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm unable to connect to the server via Jmeter.

While trying to connect via SAML protocol, the request is blocked and 401 error is returned in the response.

Can anyone guide me to resolve this issue?

any solutions please :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per [HTTP Status 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `401 Unauthorized` response status code indicates that the client request has not been completed because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the requested resource.

Most probably the request you're executing doesn't provide valid authentication context due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start).

SAML login flow assumes multiple mandatory dynamic parameters which need to be extracted from the previous request using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), saved into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and used in the next requests instead of recorded values.

See [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites) for example test plan.

Comment: hello, i used HTTP Authorization Manager to solved this issue, but still make failed the scenario. So please I didn't catch how to use SAML SSO Secured into JMeter.  :(